# Let K1 and K2 be parallel lines with line K3 passing through both of them. Points A, H are not located on these lines.

Tags: geometry

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be parallel lines with line $K_3$ passing through both of them. Points $A$ and $H$ are not located on these lines. Points $C$ and $F$ are on line $K_3$. Draw $AG$, $AH$ and $AF$. Point $E$ is on line $AF$ such that $EC$ is perpendicular to $DC$. Find the measurement of the angle at point $H$ that is labeled as $x$.

[image: diagram]

I noticed that if we extend $CE$ and $AG$ so that they intersect at a point ($x$), $AXDC$ will be a cyclic quadrilateral. Same for $CH$ and $AG$.

Comment: Ok also mention what you tried. If somebody solves it, they may help you.

Comment: $EC$ perpendicular to $DC$? Is it a typo or the diagram is labelled wrong?

Comment: Also the question does not seem complete in words. Is the diagram (and angles mentioned in the diagram) part of the question and can we rely on it to solve or is the diagram your interpretation of the question?

Answer (score 1):

We have for $\triangle ECD$, by exterior angle sum,
$$\angle EDH = \angle CED + \angle ECD = 90+2\theta$$

So $\angle ADH = \angle EDH = 90+2\theta$.

For $\triangle ADH$, by exterior angle sum,
$$x=\angle DAH + \angle ADH = 90+2\theta+\theta=90+3\theta$$